# How can I solve this problem of system of equations with two unknowns?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Problem: Gaston collected 64.50 in coins of 2 and 0.50. If he has four fewer 0.50 coins than three times the number of 2 coins, how many coins does he have of each denomination?

I think the first equation is: 2*x + 0,5*y = 64,50

x -> the amount of 2 coins

y -> the amount of 0,50 coins

But I don't know how to make the second one.

Comment: The number of 0.50 coins is four less than three times the number of 2.00 coins. That’s your equation.